# Update property in ViewModel also if there are Validation-Errors

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, xaml, mvvm

In my application I have the following definition of a `DataGridTemplateColumn`:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Placeholder-Name" Width="*">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox IsEditable="True" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="2"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.AvailablePlaceholders, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"
                      DisplayMemberPath="PlaceholderName"
                      Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource ComboBoxErrorTemplate}">
                <ComboBox.Text>
                    <Binding Path="PlaceholderName" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                        <Binding.ValidationRules>
                            <local:PlaceholderValidationRule>
                                <local:PlaceholderValidationRule.PlaceholderValidationRuleParamData>
                                    <local:PlaceholderValidationRuleParamData 
                                        UsedPlaceholders="{Binding Source={StaticResource proxy}, Path=Data.PlaceholderItems}"
                                        AvailablePlaceholders="{Binding Source={StaticResource proxy}, Path=Data.AvailablePlaceholders}"/>
                                </local:PlaceholderValidationRule.PlaceholderValidationRuleParamData>
                            </local:PlaceholderValidationRule>
                        </Binding.ValidationRules>
                    </Binding>
                </ComboBox.Text>
            </ComboBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Everything works fine with this, but I just realized that if PlaceholderValidationRule reports a not valid result, the property PlaceholderName in my ViewModel where the `ComboBox`-Text is bound to will not be updated.

Is there any way to update the property in the ViewModel from the View also if there are Validation-Errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to update the property in the ViewModel from the View also if there are Validation-Errors?

Set the `ValidationStep` property of the `ValidationRule` to `UpdatedValue`:

```
<local:PlaceholderValidationRule ValidationStep="UpdatedValue">
```

This will cause the validation rule to be run *after* the source property has been updated.

Comment: That works. Just needed to chage my ValidationRule that the value in the Validate-Method is not a string any more